# AutoLayout won't content fit UITableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I attempted to follow what I've read here on how to content-fit UITableView cells. However, the cells are still clipping content. See below:

The cell: (Connected to my custom cell class)
[image]

The constraints: (All constraints set to the ContentView)
[image]

The custom cell class:

```
    import UIKit

class S360SSessionTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var iconImg:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var locationLbl:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateLbl:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startTimeLbl:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var endTimeLbl:UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

The implementation:
These are the only table related methods. In addition, I have this in viewDidLoad: `myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0`

```
//Table Datasource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:S360SSessionTableCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("S360SSessionTableCell") as? S360SSessionTableCell

        if ((cell == nil)){
            tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: XIBFiles.SESSIONTABLECELL, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "S360SSessionTableCell")
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("S360SSessionTableCell") as? S360SSessionTableCell
        }

        var session = sessions[indexPath.row]
        cell!.locationLbl.text = (session["location"] as! String) + " - " + "Court " + (String(session["subname"]))
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM. dd, yyyy"
        cell!.dateLbl.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(session["startDate"] as! NSDate)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        cell!.startTimeLbl.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(session["startDate"] as! NSDate)
        cell!.endTimeLbl.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(session["endDate"] as! NSDate)

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sessions.count
    }
```

However, the cells still appear clipped, like so:

[image]

I am targeting iOS9.3, and it was my understanding that using AutoLayout, the default for cell height was an automatic content fit, one of the perks of the iOS8.0 changes made.

Where am I going wrong with this? I want the cells to fit the content they have and not clip it.

Comment: You need to implement tableView.rowHeight = UITableviewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a direct line of constraints from the top of the cell to the bottom. In other words,  This image from Ray Wenderlich illustrates that very well [image]

From Ray Wenderlich

> Furthermore, you need a clear line of constraints going from the top to the bottom of the contentView. This ensures that auto layout correctly determines the height of the contentView based on its subviews.

Comment: My understanding was that was the default now. However, I did add that line, and nothing changed.

Comment: @steventnorris do you have a direct line of constraints from the top of your cell to the bottom? In other words are there vertical constrains the can connect from the top to the bottom through your cell's subviews?

Comment: @steventnorris it doesn't look like you Start time label is not constrained to the top of your content view...see my edit above

Comment: @steventnorris no problem happy to help! Also, after looking at your profile it looks like I'm just down the street from you! haha I work at Asurion on 2nd and Korean Vets. Small world

Comment: Small world for sure. I work over on Church and 6th. Check me out on linked at http://www.linkedin.com/in/steventnorris if you ever want to contact me. Always good to know more tech contacts in the area.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from given answer you could try other way as below,
Apply the constraints accordingly to your subviews and labels and in viewdidappear do the following,

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Please refer the following link for more details,

[Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html).

You can also check the following for a sample
[Table View Cells with Varying Row Heights](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights/)